# Как установить zoom на карте

Tags: google-maps, масштабирование, карты, zoom

Есть ссылка, нужно чтоб было масштабирование (GMAP3)

```
<a class="button popup-map" href="#" data-box="61.219025, 31.325120">SHOW MAP</a>
```

1. `data-box="61.219025, 31.325120, zoom:10",`
2. `data-box="61.219025, 31.325120, z=10"`

пробовал так, но не получается

на странице больше 20 таких ссылок, индивидуальных , longitude latitude, google map,

*После нажатия на ссылку открывается карта, но не в зуме, тоесть без зума,*

Comment: Это вообще про что?

Comment: на странице больше 20 таких ссылок, индивидуальных , longitude latitude, google map, карта открывается, но зум не получается сделать

Comment: Ну так вы б в самом вопросе написали бы о каких картах и библиотеках идёт речь. Мы должны угадывать?

Comment: извиняюсь, исправлю!

Comment: data-box это же просто атрибут, надо знать, что происходит после нажатия на ссылку. Полагаю, что есть некий обработчик события, который парсит значение атрибута и вызывает соответствующий метод google maps javascript api (setCenter)